# File deletion in python gives strange behaviour

Tags: python

Spent over 2 hrs banging in the problem but no rescue. I am trying to delete files in a folder(windows) with python script. Below are the steps i am doing:

1. Finding all files in directory along with absolute file name and directory

   ```
   for origFile in os.listdir(base_dir):
       if origFile.endswith(".log"):
           fullFileName = os.path.abspath(origFile)
           fileDir = os.path.dirname(fullFileName)`
   ```
2. print file name and then delete the files using below statement

   ```
   os.remove(os.path.join(fileDir,origFile))
   ```

I get an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified: 'C:\Users\N93203\File CleanUp\swiftmics1_SILog -
>   Copy.log'

Its automatically adding `"\\"`  instead of `"\"`  and hence file cannot be found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling `abspath()` on a filename returned by `listdir()` is meaningless; this will produce a full pathname based on the current working directory, *not* the directory passed to `listdir()`.  What you want to get the real pathname is `os.path.join(base_dir, origFile)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double `\` is just a way to represent the string, there is no double backslashes.

You can double check it by counting the backslashes with `os.path.join(fileDir, origFile).count('\\')`

However, `os.remove(os.path.join(baseDir, origFile))` should work if it is in your if block

As mentionned in the comments, joinning on `abspath` is meaningless as it will produce a full name from current work directory and not the one you want which is `base_dir`.

Be sure to join on `baseDir`

Comment: At first, I thought this is just a "works for me", but you sneakily replaced the `fileDir` with `baseDir`, which is the actual fix to the problem. I think you should point this out more.

Comment: @tobias_k You are totally right, thanks for pointing out instead of downvoting

Comment: In my experience, downvoting without pointing out the problem rarely leads to improvement. Besides, the answer was not wrong, just a bit unclear.

Comment: Thank you both @tobias_k,@BlueSheepToken , Thanks for pointing out that i should use baseDir. Whole time i didn't see the error message , that was pointing all the time that file i am deleting doesn't exist and it really didn't exit. switching to baseDir did the trick.